# with or without "a": towards [a] green and sustainable growth

Tags: articles, definite-article

> We move towards green and sustainable growth
>
> We move towards **a** green and sustainable growth

Is 'a' a must here?

Comment: Using 'a' is not mandatory, but it is permissible in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Either would be acceptable there.

The indefinite article implies that this particular growth  is an instance of "green and sustainable growth", or that there are many kinds of growth and that the one being moved towards is of the "green and sustainable" variety.